# How can I monitor traffic matching a IP address?

Tags: juniper, monitoring

I see this [article](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/monitor-traffic.html):

> user@host> monitor traffic matching “port 22” no-resolve

there can matching a `port`

and I can matching `arp` too:

```
user@host> monitor traffic matching “arp” no-resolve
```

but, how can I matching a IP address?

if I matching

```
user@host> monitor traffic matching “192.0.2.22” no-resolve
```

there will get syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the host keyword.  As in:

```
user@host> monitor traffic matching "host 192.0.2.22” no-resolve
```

Comment: @aircraft. While using the monitor command in Juniper , please remember that only packets /traffic destined to Router itself or Routing Engine will be shown on cli. You cannot capture the transit traffic by using this command. Only packets that are hit on Control plan can be captured using this command.

Comment: @aircraft. Furthermore if you want to save the output of monitor command in pcap (wireshark format) you can add the hidden knob to the monitor command like this:-         monitor traffic interface ge-1/1/0 matching "port tcp 179" no-resolve write-file test.pcap

Comment: @aircraft. The file test.pcap will stored in /var/home/Username directory.

Answer (score -1):

It's completely depends upon devices your are working with .

By Configuring filter with soucce and destination ip address traffic can be monitored

Traffic can either monity with "souce Ip address ". & *Destination ip address". Or even with service port traffic can be monitored

Example of filters Configured in juniper firewall to monitor traffic is

`Show security flow session "source -prefix"  12.14.X.X destionation destionation destionation -prefix 14.76.X.X`

Answer (score -2):

user@host> monitor traffic matching "net 192.168.1.0/24"